# Dictionary throws exception even after checked for null

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, exception

I am trying to read a value of a key from a dictionary like the following :

```
if (myDic["myKey"] != null)
{
}
```

I can see that I am checking for null, but even then it throws KeyNotFoundException. How else should I check this? Please advise!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing the behavior of `HashTable` with that of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.  The `HashTable` class will return a `null` value when the key is not present while `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` will throw an exception.

You need to either use `ContainsKey` or `TryGetValue` to avoid this problem.

```
object value;
if (myDic.TryGetValue("apple", out value)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have to disagree on "elegance"...I think its a matter of taste. I personally HATE `out` references.

Comment: @Roly, not a fan of out references either.  This is why i use the following extension method in my C# projects.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/03/23/dictionary-tkey-tvalue-trygetvalue-and-anonymous-types.aspx

Answer (score 6):

use

```
if(mydic.ContainsKey("myKey"))
```

Answer (score 4):

It throws an exception because you are trying to retrieve the value of that item (checking if the value is null), but the value can't be retrived because the key doesn't exist.

use:

```
if (myDic.ContainsKey("myKey")) {
}
```

or:

```
if (myDic.TryGetValue("myKey", out value)) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if (myDic.ContainsKey("myKey"))  
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IDictionary.Contains

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.contains.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the value associated with the key "apple" is not `null`, not if dictionary contains the key "apple". For that you would want to use:

```
if( myDic.ContainsKey("apple") )
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either Contains or TryGetValue here.

```
if (myDic.ContainsKey)
{
  // get value out of dictionary
  var myValue = myDic["myKey"];
}
```

or

```
string myValue;
if (myDic.TryGetValue("myKey", out myValue)
{
   // do something with myValue
}
```

[above example was assuming your dictionary had values of type string, but this could be anything]

The advantage of the second approach is that you can both check whether the item exists in the dictionary and get its value as a single atomic operation, rather than doing a `Contains` check first and then a second call to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most concise way of doing this is as follows:

```
SomeType myVal;
if(myDic.TryGetValue("myKey",out myVal))
{
    //good to go
}
```